# How can I speed Up EF's AddObject when used with SQL Azure?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database

I am using EF6.1(Object Context), ASP.NET 4.5, MVC3, SQL Server 2008 SP2 on Dev, and SQL Azure on Test and Live.

I was using:

var myNewOrder = new {SupplierId=myNewSupplierId};
 db.AddObject(myNewOrder);
 db.SaveChanges();

While this approach is quick on the Dev machine ie 50ms, on SQL Azure, it can take 400ms. When I convert this to use ExecuteStoreCommand:

```
db.ExecuteStoreCommand("INSERT INTO Order ([SupplierId]) Values ({0})", mySupplierId);
```

It takes about 40ms on SQL Azure.

I have not altered any of the config object for AddObject. Is there anyway I can speed up options for AddObject. A colleague did mention "Tracking" can take a long time, but I know little about this.

So is it possible to speed up AddObject, for use on SQL Azure, and if so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: Tracking a single object cannot take 360ms. Probably some EF one-time initialization. Measure the 2nd row you insert.

Comment: Thanks for this. Will do. Yes I definitely see an an initial penalty of first call, which must be to do with initialisation/compilation, but I have also noticed a significant gain in performance when using db.ExecuteStoreCommand("INSERT...." type commands over AddObject.